# Как организовать подобную страницу на WP?

Tags: php, wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
я думаю что года это рубрики, а TENNIS - BIGMARKETS - 2017 и подобное это подрубрики. Там где таблица с месяцами, как я понимаю это в цикле новая строка как новый пост. а в этом посте уже шорткод с таблицей от плагина tablepress. Но пока с рубриками не получается. Может будет лучше все как то по другому оформить?

Comment: Я делал справочник с огромным колвом рубрик-подрубрик и постави, тестовый [урл](http://ogp.ws-at.com) Если тебе что-то такое, могу сбросить шаблон.

Comment: Да, очень похожее, сбрасывайте, спасибо!

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/hGRjElbn38qqER Держи!